# Is this situation Pareto Optimal

Tags: pareto-efficiency

"If either player is receiving his maximum payoff, then that outcome is Pareto optimal."

Is this True,False or Uncertain.

Solution: I guessed it **false** because we dont know the exact Utility function but there might be a situation where Y can increase its Utility even when X has maximum payoff.So it cannot be PO